# ServiceControler.GetServices() silently bailing in a background thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running the following line to get a list of all services for a given computer:

```
ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(compName);
```

If I run this on the **main thread** and pass in a computer name that exists but I don't have permissions to view the services for, such as:

```
ServiceController.GetServices("OtherComp");
```

> InvalidOperationException:
>   Cannot open Service Control Manager on computer 'OtherComp'. This operation might require other privileges.

I fully expect this to happen. However my issue comes with running this on a **background thread**. Take this fully complete console program:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;

namespace ServiceTesting
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceAccessor sa = new ServiceAccessor();
            sa.Run();
        }
    }

    public class ServiceAccessor
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw;

        public ServiceAccessor()
        {
            bw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bw_DoWork);
            bw.RunWorkerCompleted += new
                RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            //this line is where the bail happens
            var services = ServiceController.GetServices("OtherComputer");
        }

        void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // the code will never get to this method
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I would expect an exception to be thrown, but as soon as the code tries to execute this line, it bails out of the thread.**

I can't wrap the line in a `try\catch`; it will won't catch it. This might be simmilar to `ThreadAbort` problems with asp.net (but that is just a guess).

The [msdn page on the ServiceController Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX) says that the static function is thread safe, however, a commenter on the [function's msdn page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.getservices%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) says that it is not.

Answer (score 1):

Exception was catched by BackgroundWorker internally, you can view it via RunWorkerCompleted event:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(
    object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // First, handle the case where an exception was thrown. 
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        // deal with error
    }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.runworkercompletedeventargs.aspx

UPD: However, it works as expected with Thread class:

```
new Thread(() =>
    {
        try
        {
            var services = ServiceController.GetServices("OtherComputer");
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }).Start();
```

Comment: I have updated my question to include this example. However, the code will never reach that function. What I find odd is that when the exception line is ran in the main thread, it takes about 8-15 seconds to throw an exception, but in the other thread, it bails instantaneously.

Comment: I can't find a reason why BackgroundWorker fails to catch that exception, however it works as expected with plain thread.

Comment: Exactly, which is why this is so strange to me.

Comment: Drats, I was using a Backgroundworker for the convenance. I would prefer to keep using that, but I'll switch to regular threads if needed.