# BackgroundWorker capture error

Tags: c#, exception

I've been trying to follow this MSDN [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), and using the code below. However, `e.Error` is ALWAYS null in RunWorkerCompleted even when an error does occur in SomeMethod();

```
private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   getMethod = SomeMethod();
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender,
                                             RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error != null)
    {
        var result = ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Error occurred.... " +
                                   e.Result, "ErrorTitle", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
    else if (e.Cancelled)
    {

    }
    Else
    {

    }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I can get around it by doing the following but I don't really understand why the example in MSDN is not working for me?

```
private void WorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        getMethod = SomeMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        e.Result = ex;
    }
}

private void Worker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.Result is Exception)
    {
            var result = ModernDialog.ShowMessage("Error occurred.... " + e.Result, "ErrorTitle", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }

    //etc
}
```

Also, using the second method I can't access the .Message from e.Result. For example, in WorkerDoWork I can use `ex.Message`

Edit: I've setup the worker to create it's own error and I still get e.Error == null. The variable displayed is a bit faint as CTRL+PrtSc makes it fade
[image]

Comment: In WinForms, I cannot duplicate the issue.  Are you sure you aren't catching the error somewhere?

Comment: Definitely not catching the error, SomeMethod(); contains no try,catch statements. It's in a WPF app if that makes a difference?

Comment: Take a look at [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793377/servicecontroler-getservices-silently-bailing-in-a-background-thread), which might be relivent.

Comment: Can't duplicate in WPF either.  I always get `e.Error != null` when I throw an exception in the DoWork method.

Comment: What about if throwing the error in SomeMethod()?

Comment: No difference.  You might have to show what you are doing in your SomeMethod procedure.

Comment: I'm getting really strange behaviour then. I'm removed the method and fixed the worker to raise an error. I still get e.Error == null??? WTF. See update image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem is your empty exception block in `emailWorkerDoWork()`. For the result to be an exception you can't catch the exceptions in your background worker.

So something like this should give you the desired result:

```
private void emailWorkerDoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int value = 1 / int.Parse("0");
}
```

I found another SO answer that confirms my suspicion and provides a MSFT reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/258664/1346943).

Comment: Great, it's now working. Thanks for everyone's help.